# (Inequality) $p \cdot (z-x) \leq \frac{a}{R} | z- x| \Leftrightarrow |p|\leq \frac{a}{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to solve this inequality:

Let $z \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $a,R > 0$, prove that

$$(\forall x\in B_R(z)) \quad p \cdot (z-x) \leq \frac{a}{R} | z- x|  \ \Longleftrightarrow  \ |p|\leq \frac{a}{R} $$

Its seem to be very elementary inequality but I can't solve it :(.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose we have $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, in that case, if $|p|\leq \frac{a}{R}$, we have the so-called Cauchy-inequality. Take a look at it, put your vectors into it and you're almost done.

If, however $|p|>\frac{a}{R}$, we can then choose $x$ such that $z-x=c\cdot p$ for $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$ (why?). In that case, our inequality certainly will not hold, thus we are done.

Comment: I don't see why the conclusion follows from $z-x = c \cdot p$

Comment: If we have $z-x=c\cdot p$, then we can simply put that into our inequality: $p\cdot (z-x)=c \cdot (p \cdot p)=c\cdot|p|^2>\frac{a}{R}c\cdot |p|$, since $|p|>\frac{a}{R}=|z-x|\frac{a}{R}$. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

By the dot product rule 
$$p\cdot (z-x)=|p||z-x|\cos\theta$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the vector $p$ and $z-x$. Now let 
$$|p|\leq\frac{a}{R}\Rightarrow |p||z-x|\leq\frac{a}{R}|z-x|$$
But $$p\cdot (z-x)=|p||z-x|\cos\theta\leq|p||z-x|$$
So $$p\cdot(z-x)\leq\frac{a}{R}|z-x|$$
This is about this direction, but I cant see the other direction. Because lets say 
$$p\cdot(z-x)\leq\frac{a}{R}|z-x|\Rightarrow |p||z-x|\cos\theta\leq\frac{a}{R}|z-x|\Rightarrow |p|\cos\theta\leq\frac{a}{R}$$
But this does not ensure $|p|\leq\frac{a}{R}$ because you could have $\cos\theta=1/2$ and $|p|=\frac{2a}{R}$.